# Thunderbird sometimes renders decrypted content in its encrypted form when it is quoted in replies

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird with built-in OpenPGP encryption.
It works but I have a problem when I receive mail from specific accounts.

Usually, when I receive an encrypted message, it's decrypted on the fly when I click on it (I don't see the encrypted content with the "Decrypt" button); when I reply to the message, the quoted message text is displayed unencrypted, and the entire message is encrypted once I send it. And that's what I want.

When I receive messages from certain senders, it's also decrypted on the fly when I click on it, but when I reply to the message, the quoted message text is displayed in its encrypted form, as seen in the following image:

[image: message with quoted encrypted content]

What's wrong with the message? How can I reply to it and quote the unencrypted message text as is typically the case?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Thunderbird to me. You should it report it to its maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the root of the problem. By analysing mail envelopes I've noticed that Thunderbird was sending the encrypted mail in `utf-8`

```
...
Charset: utf-8
...
```

That was different from the charset used by the mail that I've received (as you can see in the question image is `iso-8859-1`. I've asked the sender to try to change the charset in `utf-8` in the options of his mail client, and everything started to work again.